# How to run a command once the first time the OS is used?

Tags: system-installation, login, startup, dialog, zenity

I am customizing OS and want to display a dialogue describing the ad hoc OS the first time the user is entering the OS. The command is saved in a script.

**What is the best strategy to execute a script (here launching a dialogue) only once when the OS is discovered and the user first log in?**

**Proposed strategy:**

*Add a `if` statement to the script to execute only if a specific file `myfile` is non-empty and empty this file at the end the script.*

```
    if [ $(cat myfile ) ]
       then
    my_dialogue_command
    echo ""> myfile
    fi
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution is to parse `lastlog -u <username>` before execution. If there's "never logged in" in the output, then you return immediately. You can then define your script in .bash_profile to execute it on (first) login.

The script can be executed once by self-deleting it at the end:

```
rm $0
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/156771/run-a-script-only-at-the-very-first-boot